# "Unpack" an array to call a function with variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm using the ben strasser C++ fast csv parser: https://github.com/ben-strasser/fast-cpp-csv-parser. It uses a variadic template to pass column values back to the while loop that processes the csv data:

```
io::CSVReader<2> in(csv_filename);
double x, y;
while(in.read_row(x,y)) {
    //code with x and y
}
```

This calls the following function in the CSVReader class:

```
template<class ...ColType>
bool read_row(ColType& ...cols){
    //snip
}
```

This works fine for me with my x and y values. However, I would like to expand this to use arbitrary dimensions. This means my data has a (known) number of columns I need to read. I would like to use something like this:

```
io::CSVReader<known_dimension> in(csvfname);
double data[known_dimension];
while(in.read_row(data)) {
    //code with data[0],data[1],...,data[known_number]
}
```

However, this is not valid syntax. I need to "unpack" the array of doubles into separate arguments of pointers to my doubles. I'd like to do this without modifications to the fast csv parser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`std::integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) for that purpose:

```
namespace Detail
{
template <typename Reader, typename T, std::size_t... I>
void read_row(Reader& in, T* data, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
     in.read_row(data[I]...); // A trick here
} 

}

template <std::size_t N, typename T>
void read_row(io::CSVReader<N>& in, T* data)
{
     Detail::read_row(in, data, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

And of course, use like this:

```
int a[7];
io::CSVReader<7> r;
read_row(r, a);
```

"Working" example: [link](http://ideone.com/EiWjBm)

---

For compiler "below" C++14 - `integer_sequence` (actually just `index_sequence` needed) is pretty easy to implement:

```
template <std::size_t... I>
class index_sequence {};
```

And `make_index_sequence` not so easy - but also doable:

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t ...I>
struct make_index_sequence : make_index_sequence<N-1, N-1,I...> {};

template <std::size_t ...I>
struct make_index_sequence<0,I...> : index_sequence<I...> {};
```

Comment: While it is a good answer, `std::integer_sequence` is from C++14, question is tagged for C++11.

Comment: @SergeyA - true - I added implementation of this for C++11

Comment: That *almost* works. I get the following error message: no matching function for call to 'read_row(io::CSVReader<2u>&, double [2])'. Note: candidate is: template<long unsigend int N, class T> void read_row(io::CSVReader<N>&,T*). Template argument deduction/substitution failed: mismatched types long unsigned int and '#'ínteger_cst' not supported by dump_type#<type error>'. 'io::CSVReader<2u>' is not derived from 'io::CSVReader<N>'

Comment: Well, I figured it out. For anyone who encounters the same problem: g++ needs to be at least version 4.9.0 for this to work. In the earlier versions there is a bug that prevents this from working: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57638

Comment: @ThijsMiedema - just change `std::size_t` to `unsigned`

Comment: I did that too actually, still wouldn't compile on my g++4.3 but did on g++4.9.