# Unpack C-style array along with parameter pack in C++

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

My question is somewhat similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34929856/unpack-an-array-to-call-a-function-with-variadic-template): I'm using C++14 and I'm trying to "unpack" a C-style array and call a function with its content. The difference is, I need to do that in a variadic function template and pass each element of the array into something that depends on the type parameter pack.

Here is the simplified code:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct Converter {
   static T convert(const char*) {
     ...
   }
};

template<typename ... T>
void myfunction( void(*f)(T...), char* args[]) {
    f(Converter<T...>::convert(args[i])...); // this is not correct but illustrates the idea
}
```

`myfunction` here takes a pointer to a function `f` accepting an arbitrary number of arguments of type T1, ... Tn. Each element of the `args` array should be converted to the corresponding type before being passed to `f`.

How can I do that in C++14?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that creates a compile time integer sequence that you can use to index `args`:

```
template<typename ...T, size_t ...I>
void myfunction_impl(void(*f)(T...), char const* args[], std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    f(Converter<T>::convert(args[I])...); 
}

template<typename ... T, size_t N>
void myfunction(void(*f)(T...), char const *(&args)[N]) {
    static_assert(N == sizeof...(T), "");
    myfunction_impl(f, args, std::index_sequence_for<T...>());
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/QDyx3H).

This also uses the size of the array passed in, to `static_assert` that it's equal to the number of parameters of the function passed in.